# How do I reduce CPU and memory usage by a python program?

Tags: python, performance, cpu-usage, raspberry-pi, cpu-speed

I have a python program that uses a lot of my CPU's resources. While it is fine on my regular PC, I'm afraid it might be too much to handle for my Raspberry Pi. Speed is not an issue. I don't care if my code is executed slowly as I am implementing a real time system that executes the code only once every few hours, but my CPU needs to be freed up as I would also be running other processes simultaneously. Is there anyway I can reduce the resources that it takes from the CPU  at the cost of speed of execution? Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: We need to see code in order to help. You do not mention anything about what the program does. The only thing i can suggest without seeing code is ensure loops and threads are using adequate blocking / sleeping whilst waiting for information to process.

Comment: It would be really helpful to have some idea of what you're doing and how you're doing it. In general, the strategy for speeding up Python is to isolate the most CPU-intensive parts of your code using profiling and then rewrite them using C or Cython.

Comment: I am using a neural network from the PyBrain library. Is there a way to limit the CPU usage for the entire program? I'm using Debian in my Raspberry Pi, is there a way to do this in linux or within python itself?

Comment: I do not wish to speed up the program, I want to decrease the resources allocated to python itself at the cost of slowing down the program. Speed is no issue to me. I just don't want it to freeze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you sure can tinker with your program and make it more optimized, the fact is that all programs are generally designed to take as much CPU as they need in order to finish in smallest time possible.

I see two ways to achieve your goal:

1. Raspberry pi is Linux right? So just lower process priority of the python interpreter running your script. this would make sure that other programs can have CPU if they need it
2. In your script, sleep for few milliseconds every few milliseconds.. ugly, but could do the trick

But option one is probably way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I hadn't thought of option one. I will probably try the sleep as well in combination. Much appreciated

Comment: @user17151 I suggest you first try just lowering the priority because code with so much sleep would be reaaaaally ugly ;)

ps: and depending on your implementation could be hard to debug

Comment: Yes I will thanks. I will keep it as a last resort to use the sleep.